# How to full name of a symbol into a tree?

Tags: scala, reflection

Trying to wrap my head around scala reflection finally.

I got something like this in a macro:

```
val endpoints = c.mirror
 .staticModule(serviceType.name.toString + "Endpoints")
 .info

val wrapped = service.decls.collect { case m: MemberSymbol => 
   val ep = endpoints.member(m.name)
   q"wrapEndpoint(ep.name.toTermName)"
}.toList

c.Expr[List[WrappedEndpoint]](wrapped)
```

So, basically, there is

```
trait MyService { 
   def foo(bar: String): String
}

object MyServiceEndpoints { 
   val foo: Endpoint = ???
}
```

And then I do `val wrapped: List[WrappedEndpoint] = wrap[MyService]`

It works fine, but I have to `import MyServiceEndpoints._` at call site, which I don't want to have to do :(

So, the question is, what incantation do I have to chant instead of
`ep.name.toTermName` to use the fully qualified name instead?

I tried `ep.fullName`, but that does not compile, because it is a String, and it wants `TermName`
I tried `TermName(ep.fullName)`, but that puts name in backticks (like this:

```
wrapEndpoint(`foo.bar.baz.MyServiceEndpoints.foo`)
```

I tried `Ident(TermName(ep.fullName))`, but it doesn't seem to make any difference from just `TermName`
I tried `Literal(Constant(ep.fullName))`, but that results in a double-quoted String.

What else haven't I tried?

Comment: While it isn't entiery clear to me what you want to do, for class names, objects, vals in objects, etc in Scala 2 macros I would suggest using fully qualified names only, additionally prepending them with `_root_`. Quasiquotes usually make this easier with some `q"_root_.foo.bar.baz.MyServiceEndpoints.foo"` (except when the quasiquotes don't work, and you have to use AST). And if you already obtained a `Symbol`, as far as I remember, you can use it in quasiquotes instead of TermName/Ident e.g. `q"${typeSymbol.asClass.module}.${methodSymbol}"`.